# Trying to make an app which encrypt and decrypt the text using AES scheme

Tags: java, android, string, encryption, aes

in this app, the encrypt button is running at the desired functionality, but the decrypt button is not showing any output. after the decrypt function executes, it returns an empty string, I am not getting the fault, also there is no error. I think there is any logical error.

*the code for global variables and on click listeners are: *

```
 EditText input_text,password_text;
    TextView output_text;
    Button enc,dec;
    String outputstring;
    String AES="AES";
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input_text =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
        password_text=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
        output_text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_text);
        enc=(Button) findViewById(R.id.encrypt);
        dec=(Button) findViewById(R.id.decrypt);
        final String pwdtext=password_text.getText().toString();
        final String inptext=input_text.getText().toString();

        enc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               try{
                   outputstring=encrypt(inptext,pwdtext);
                output_text.setText(outputstring);
               } catch (Exception e)
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        });

        dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             try{
                 outputstring=decrypt(outputstring,pwdtext);
                 output_text.setText(outputstring);
             } catch (Exception e)
             {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

            }
        });
    }
```

*the code for the encrypt method id:*

```
 private String encrypt(String data,String password_text) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(password_text);
    Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] encVal=c.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    String encryptedvalue= Base64.encodeToString(encVal,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedvalue;
}
```

*The code for the decrypt method is:*

```
private String decrypt(String outputstring,String password_text) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(password_text);
    Cipher c =Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] decodedvalue =Base64.decode(outputstring,Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decvalue=c.doFinal(decodedvalue);
    String decryptedvalue=new String(decvalue);
    return decryptedvalue;
}
```

*the code for the generate key method is:*

```
 private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception{
    final MessageDigest digest=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes=password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    byte[] key=digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
```

Comment: Post the code to encrypt first. Followed by the code to decrypt the encrypted stuff. Make it reproducable so we only have to copy/paste.

Comment: I have posted the code for encrypt method.

Comment: Ah, and `generateKey` is from that idiotic Android snippets site with the SHA1PRNG secure random?

Comment: Please also show how and with which data you call encrypt(). And use the result to call decrypt(). Do not use code like editText().getText() as we than do not know the data. Put just sting literals in your code.

Comment: @greenapps I have added all the stuff you want

Comment: No you did not. `outputstring=encrypt(inptext,pwdtext);` We cannot see the value of the parameters. So we cannot test your code with the same strings. Look how Nikhil Lotke did it.

Comment: @greenapps I have added them, see above the definition of the onClickListeners, they are declared there.

Comment: No.  `outputstring=encrypt(inptext,pwdtext);`  We still cannot see the values for your parameters. Also `final String inptext=input_text.getText().toString();'` Does not tell us what the user of your app typed in. Look again how Nikhil Lotke did it.
`

Comment: I asked you to post the code how you called your functions and with which data. I expected someting like `String data = "we will encrypt this text"; String password = "mysecret"; String encrypted = encrypt(data,  password); String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, password); if ( !decrypted.equals(data)) Toast ( .. something went wrong ... ); else ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your latest code i setup same again at my end and here is the working code below which should work 100%

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESEncryptDecryptNew extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText input_text, password_text;
TextView output_text;
Button enc, dec;
String outputstring;
String AES = "AES";
String pwdtext;
String inptext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    input_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    password_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_text);
    output_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output_text);
    enc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.encrypt);
    dec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrypt);

    enc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                inptext = input_text.getText().toString();
                pwdtext = password_text.getText().toString();
                outputstring = encrypt(inptext, pwdtext);
                output_text.setText(outputstring);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


    dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                inptext = input_text.getText().toString();
                pwdtext = password_text.getText().toString();
                outputstring = decrypt(outputstring, pwdtext);
                output_text.setText(outputstring);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

private String encrypt(String data, String password_text) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password_text);
    Log.d("NIKHIL", "encrypt key:" + key.toString());
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encryptedvalue = Base64.encodeToString(encVal, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedvalue;

}

private String decrypt(String data, String password_text) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password_text);
    Log.d("NIKHIL", "encrypt key:" + key.toString());
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decodedvalue = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decvalue = c.doFinal(decodedvalue);
    String decryptedvalue = new String(decvalue, "UTF-8");
    return decryptedvalue;
}

private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
}
```

Your missing things in updated code are:
1. You are not considering input password at the time of encrypt or decrypt button onclick.
2. You should create global variable for pwdtext and inptext

Hope this is clear now.
If this works then please approve the answer

Comment: now the code is working for me , thank you. but now there is another problem it is giving different outputs for the same set of inputs on different devices, I want it to give same output irrespective of the device. that's the final problem , please help me .

Comment: @LoveBabbar can you please approve the answer.

Comment: I have approved your answer, now can you help me please in the above stated problem

Comment: What do you mean by different outputs here? It should be same like input value only. I tried on 4 devices now and all 4 of them are giving me same result

Comment: suppose I am using an input "hello" and password as "qwerty" and then press the encrypt button , I get some data in encrypted format and when this encrypted data is decrypted with the same in the other devices i.e. in the other device I m taking the encrypted data as the input data and key same as before and press the decrypt button.Ideally it should "hello" as output , but it is not able to fulfil this functionality.

Comment: How do you transfer the base64 encoded string to the other device?

Answer (score 0):

I setup your code at my end and here is what i tried and is working now:

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String outputstring = "This is my output data";
String passwordText = "Nikhil Lotke";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        outputstring = encrypt(outputstring,passwordText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TextView dec = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dec);
    dec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                Log.d("NIKHIL",decrypt(outputstring,passwordText));

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}

private String encrypt(String data,String password_text) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(password_text);
    Log.d("NIKHIL","encrypt key:"+key.toString());
    Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] encVal=c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encryptedvalue= Base64.encodeToString(encVal,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedvalue;

}

private String decrypt(String data, String password_text) throws Exception
{
    SecretKeySpec key=generateKey(password_text);
    Log.d("NIKHIL","encrypt key:"+key.toString());
        Cipher c =Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
    byte[] decodedvalue =Base64.decode(data,Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decvalue=c.doFinal(decodedvalue);
    String decryptedvalue=new String(decvalue,"UTF-8");
    return decryptedvalue;
}

private SecretKeySpec generateKey(String password) throws Exception{
    final MessageDigest digest=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes=password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    byte[] key=digest.digest();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}
}
```

**Your missing things are:**

1. Cipher c =Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"); in both encrypt and decrypt functions
2. UTF-8 in doFinal ... byte[] encVal=c.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Comment: Nikhil your code is working definitely , but I take input from the textview then the problem remains the same . I have edited the post , now you can see the variables , textviews and editTexts in the code. Please try to rectify the above code with taking input fro the textview and printing out the answer in the button click event

Comment: @LoveBabbar Please check my answer with working code base below with separate comment